# Inserting chapter/section dependent figures in lyx

Tags: graphics, sectioning, lyx, chapters

How can I insert figures that change with sectioning? Right now I include figures using the following latex snippet:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{images/figure.png}\caption{ This is a figure in some chapter and section }
\end{figure}
```

and in the actual work refer to it only as Figure x.x where x.x is the section and figure number. If I change the section I also have to manually change all figure names to match the new sections. Is it possible to link Figure names/references to the section they are used in?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually changing the figure names'? `\caption` does this for you automatically. Perhaps you mean something like `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` (using `chngcntr` package) but this does not necessarily mean that the figures have the numbers you expeced, due to floating!

Comment: Your example code does not contain a `\label` command (but should, after `\caption{...}`). How then do you refer to your figure if you haven't assigned a label?

Comment: @gernot I do not refer to it. I used latex to insert the figure and then simply mention its name in the rest of the text. I have no link between the figure's number and its use.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I change the name of the figure manually in the rest of the text. For example if there is Figure 3.1 in Chapter 3 and Chapter 3 becomes Chapter 4 I have to change the name of the figure to Figure 4.1.

Comment: Please read any LaTeX documentation about labeling and cross-referencing, like [LaTeX/Labels and Cross-referencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing). You should never refer to sections, figures, theorems or whatever directly by typing the corresponding number literally. Instead, assign labels with the `\label` command (a label is an almost arbitrary string), and then refer to the section/figure/whatsoever using the `\ref` command with this label.

Comment: Using lyx you can insert floating figure, then in it insert the graphics. In the caption insert a label (all from the insert menu) then when referring use the insert cross reference gui

Comment: I used it initially but I couldn't control the image position within pages (all my  figures were shifted to the right).

Comment: The use of `\label` and `\ref` has no effect on the position of the figure. Without a minimal example, we can't say what was wrong, but only that something else in your code must have been responsible for the problem.

Comment: @Sebi: Learning LaTeX correctly by reading documentation and introduction to LaTeX is much more efficient than using such 'tools' as LyX etc.

Comment: I tried to use a text editor vim in the beginning but I can't manage large pieces of work. I can barely manage around 15 pages (the average size of a chapter).

Comment: @Sebi: I've managed writing about 50000 lines of C - Code by using `emacs` as well as writing my PhD thesis with emacs, about 15 years ago ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's quite an accomplishment but I have some really tight deadlines to meet and am trying to abstract away from my work as much as possible. lyx seemed like a good choice when I started.

Comment: There are GUI editors which may be easier to learn than vim or emacs, without the issues involved in using something like LyX. But especially if you use LyX, you need to read a basic introduction to LaTeX.